# How to append query string to url in laravel 5.3

Tags: php, laravel-5.3

I'm using laravel 5.3 and in postLogin method, I want to append api_token as query string to url as follows:

http://localhost/Exams/student/dashboard?api_token=4ZtxTu7fAwYpcPYRu46GWmVfncPO0i

My LoginController.php is:

```
public function postStudentLogin(Request $request){ 
   $student = DB::table('students')->where('email', $request->get('email'))->first();   
   if(Hash::check( $request->get('password'),$student->password))
    {       
      Session::flash('login_message','You have been logged in successfully.');  
      return redirect()->route('dashboard',['api_token'=> $student->api_token]);    
    }
    else{   
       return redirect()->back()->withErrors('Incorrect username/password');   
      } 
   }
```

and routes/web.php is:

```
Route::group(['prefix' => 'student', 'namespace' => 'Auth'], function(){
   Route::get('/','Student\LoginController@getStudentHome');    
   Route::get('/login/{page}',['uses' => 'Student\LoginController@getStudentLogin' ]);  
   Route::any('/dashboard',['uses' =>'Student\LoginController@postStudentLogin'])->name('dashboard');      
});
```

It appends api_token to dashboard , but $student always comes null in postStudentLogin() method, even though dd($student) gives complete student details.

Please guide me where I'm wrong.

Thanks,

Dipti Sheth

Comment: you want $student variable on dashboard then use view()->share('student',$student); before redirect statement. I think that might can help you..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There must be default request parameter,

```
public function postStudentLogin(Request $request){         
   $retArr = $request->all();
   // try to dd here $retArr variable, you should get everything
 }
```

Give it a try, this should work.

**EDIT**

To get only query string try this,

```
Request::getQueryString();
```

And yes, add this `use Illuminate\Http\Request;` to your namespace at the top of file.

Rest, you should get in `$request->all()`.

Comment: I've modified my loginController .php  as above , but still $student becomes null and dd($student) gives complete student details

Comment: If Hash::check() method verifies hashed password, the it will append query string to url and post page to dashboard. And to append api_token as query string, I'm fetching it from db using $student as: $student =  DB::table('students')->where('email', $request->get('email'))->first();

Comment: are you getting $request->get('email') here ?

Comment: ya..I'm getting it

Comment: dd($student):  {#199 ▼
  +"id": 27
  +"email": "student@gmail.com"
  +"password": "$2y$10$pu3JMwmCBOAtA5bg05mrl.weMQ1/VNEZ2TSi2Gye5pWLzcrJc1.aO"
  +"api_token": "4ZtxTu7fAwYpcPYRu46GWmVfncPO0iHzee7NxKqNaY1a9907BoxT1iHl2Azi"
  +"name": "student"
  +"address": "pune"
  +"phone": "6545678932"
  +"guardian_phone": ""
  +"enroll": ""
  +"photo": null
  +"status": "Active"
  +"reg_code": "0"
  +"reg_status": "Live"
  +"expiry_days": 0
  +"renewal_date": null
  +"presetcode": null
  +"created_at": "2017-02-08 11:20:44"
  +"updated_at": "2017-02-08 11:20:44"
  +"last_login": null
}

Comment: dd($student) gives me result, but when I comment it, it throws error : ErrorException in LoginController.php line 61:
Trying to get property of non-object  array('request' => object(Request), 'student' => null)) in LoginController.php line 61

Comment: that's weird, now $student becomes null, but in dd($student) it shows all details

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/135828/discussion-between-rahul-m-and-dipti-sheth).

Answer (score 8):

```
//Declare new queries you want to append to string:
$newQueries = ['foo' => 'bar', 'popular'];


//Generate the URL with all the queries:
//Retrieve current query strings with new query variable appended.
$request->fullUrlWithQuery($newQueries);
```

Answer (score 0):

For your code, can use below as per requirement.
For more refernce https://laravel.com/docs/5.3/requests

```
 // Add top of your controller
use Illuminate\Http\Request;

public function postStudentLogin(Request $request){         
         // To get all data
      $inputs = $request->input();
         // To get specific value
      $api_token = $request->input('api_token');
       ....
       ...
}
```

Comment: LoginController.php:                                                                        public function postStudentLogin(Request $request){  
      $student =  DB::table('students')->where('email', $request->get('email'))->first();   
   if(Hash::check( $request->get('password'),$student->password)){  
     Session::flash('login_message','You have been logged in successfully.');    
    return redirect()->route('dashboard',['api_token'=> $student->api_token]);    
      }
   else{         
    return redirect()->back()->withErrors('Incorrect username/password');
   } 
  }